# WordPress blog or WordPress website

Tags: posts, customization

I have created a WordPress blog. http://www.lifegetsdigital.com.wordpress.com

I am planning to eventually move all the posts to a website of my own from the free WordPress service.

Is it good move the blog to a private domain now or should i move after making some[say 100] posts using the free wordpress service?

My primary concerns for not staying with WordPress is

1) Lack of google adsense support
2) Limited facebook integration
3) I believe plugins can be better installed and managed in our own server.

Soliciting advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather clean-cut answer in my opinion, but each to their own and of course there will be varying opinions on this. The WordPress.com blog hosting service offers one major feature that self-hosted installations managed by WordPress newbies don't have: great security. It's no secret that a self-hosted WordPress installation can be a lot of work especially when it comes to locking it down against hackers.

If you want functionality the WordPress.com blog hosting doesn't offer, then I suggest you move now. If you have 100+ posts down the track, the margin of error from the exporting to the importing stage will be much higher.

If however you can't deal with the prospect of potentially having your site hacked from what seems to be an endless game of cat and mouse vulnerbilities between the core developers and exploiters, stick with Wordpress.com

Comment: i am also concerned about SEO ranking, if  i move the posts at a very late time i may need to work again to improve the SE rankings.

Comment: This is true, very true. One solution would be if you want to use Wordpress.com hosting is to purchase a domain name you'd move too at a later date and then add it on to your Wordpress.com account. So and so when the time comes to move to a self-hosted version, you can structure your URL's the same and Google won't know otherwise because nothing would have aesthetically changed, the URL's would look the same. Check out this helpful article on the Wordpress.com site which explains it: http://en.support.wordpress.com/domain-mapping/

Answer (score 0):

Better go with self-hosted wordpress so that you can monetize it right away.

Comment: Though this is technically an answer, it doesn't really speak to the heart of the question. Can you be more specific as to why they should switch? Give examples, etc...